# PHP script is downloadable with this approach. Prevention?

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

I am writing my app with this method. I want a private directory where cant be accesible via URL. So i have a htaccess where successfully redirect when you visit the photos folder. I have my files with this structure.

myApp
| []photos
| .htaccess
| loadthephoto.php
| home.php

when you visit the home.php, at one line i serve the image through loadthephoto.php. The code inside there is

```
    $resultLoad = getUserDetails($db,"photo","user_details",$_SESSION['theUserskey']);

    $photosName = $resultLoad['photo'];
    $file = 'photos/'.$photosName;
    $temp = explode(".", $photosName);
    $type = 'image/'.end($temp);

    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit();
```

It works fine. The problem is that it produce a html like this `<img src="loadthephoto.php">` ,  and if you visit the url/loadthephoto.php make this downloadable. I do not want this.

First, is this way correct for serving "private" images  ? If it can be implemented with this way, how can i make the loadthephoto.php for not be downloadable ?

Another way is to make the photos folder be accesible from url and producing the images with the classic URLs way.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? If a photo can be viewed, it can be downloaded -- there is no way to avoid this.

Comment: the myApp/loadthephoto.php script is downloadable. That the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the file mime type and/or extension before serving it. Checking an extension is not recommended as anyone could upload an image with a txt extension.

You're halfway there with your code but you're making a mime type from an extension which is also unwise as `image/jpg` isn't a proper mime type it should be `image/jpeg`.

```
$resultLoad = getUserDetails($db,"photo","user_details",$_SESSION['theUserskey']);

$photosName = $resultLoad['photo'];
$file = 'photos/' . $photosName;

// Check mime type
$mime = mime_content_type($file);

$validMimes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/svg+xml'];

// Refuse to serve invalid files
if (!in_array($mime, $validMimes)) {
    die('Invalid file type');
}

header('Content-Type:' . $mime);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit();
```

Comment: i am checking when user upload image. But i will add your code too. Thanks. The problem is that the loadthephoto.php script is downloadable. Because i am using header readfile etc.

Comment: Change `echo 'Invalid file type';` to `die('Invalid file type');` and it'll stop processing any further therefore making the file no longer downloadable unless the mime type is allowed

Comment: ok. Yes i understand. i wanted to say that, if you visit the url . myapp/loadthephoto.php . With the code that i provided. The browser alert with the download box. And you could download the php scirpt

Comment: Ah ok, using the example I provided it should simply download a text file with 'Invalid file type' in it. If the full script is downloading it might be because your host hasn't configured apache correctly.

Comment: ohh my. Haha, i thought that if i download it will have the code inside. Actually i never downloaded that to see :p . I add and if(isset($_SESSION..)else REDIRECT !!!